# how exit app on back press . in react native

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have 3 screens in stack

screen1, screen2, screen3

Now I am Navigating from Screen1 to Screen2 like this

```
props.navigation.navigate(screen2)
```

because I want to come back to screen1 by just simply android back button press.

and I am Navigating From Screen2 to Screen3 like this

```
props.navigation.replace(screen3)
```

because I dont want to come back if user press andorid back button then simply app will exit. but in my case when i press back button from screen 3 . it will redirecting to screen1.

so please help how can solve this

Comment: You need to use BackHandler for this. @Hand Code

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {BackHandler} from "react-native";

export default class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
      BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton);
  }

  handleBackButton = () => {
      BackHandler.exitApp()
  };
}
```